# Probability of selection of $D$ if $C$ is elected unanimously

Tags: probability

Five persons $A,B,C,D,E$ are contesting in an election in which $3$ persons are to be selected. If $C$ is elected unanimously, then find the probability that $D$ gets selected.

I am not able to understand the use of term unanimously here. Does it mean that the answer will be simply $$\frac{^4C_2}{^5C_3}$$?

Comment: It's not possible to find a probability since you haven't specified a distribution. Sometimes you can get away without specifying a distribution because it's sufficiently obvious which distribution is implied, but in this case I don't see any obvious distribution. A separate problem is that neither the voting method, nor the number of people voting is specified.

Comment: There's nothing to distinguish any of the non-$C$ candidates, so presumably the answer is $\frac 24$.

Answer (score 3):

$P(D \quad \!\!\text{elected})=\dfrac{N(D)}{N(S)} \quad$ where $N(D)$ is the number of ways $D$ can get elected and $N(S)$ is the total number of the sample space.

If $D$ must be elected, then $N(D)=\binom{3}{1}$ (the number of ways to arrange the remaining $3$ people).

Since $C$ must be elected regardless, $N(S)=\binom{4}{2}$ as we are trying to find the number of ways to arrange the remaining two spots from $4$ people.

$P(D\quad \!\!\text{elected})=\dfrac{3}{4\cdot3/2}=\dfrac{1}{2}$